# Live CD doesn't boot on an emac

Tags: 10.10, installation

I have tried booting from ubuntu on my emac, but when i hold down the <kbd>C</kbd> key, or any other key like option. It just continues to boot up mac os 10.3, Panther. I really want to run ubuntu on my mac, instead of mac os panther.

My specs:

1Gb of ram
800mhz ppc g4 processor
40gb hdd
Mac os 10.3, Panther.

Comment: Can the computer boot to any other CDs? Can you read the contents of the Ubuntu CD from within Mac OS X?

Comment: Hi aendruk, it can boot from other cd's, it has booted from a mac os 10.1 install disk before.but the ubuntu one doens't even show up in mac os x. I know that it's not jut my eMac, because my ibook clamshell does the same.

Comment: Do you think that it might not work because i am burning the iso to a cd using windows? If it is, how can I run Ubuntu on my eMac, because my eMac can't burn discs, it can only read them. would I maybe be able to use a flash drive?

Comment: I had a similar issue with my eMac. Are you using a non-mac keyboard?

Comment: Hi AndrewMC, I am using a 1999 apple usb keyboard (Two usb ports, power button,etc) I do also have a apple pro keyboard from around 2003.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to boot off of this CD. My guess is that the CD did not burn correctly - try making another and check the ISO file to make sure the md5sum/sha1sum matches.

Make sure you can boot off your OS X CD if you still have one. This will ensure you can actually boot from CD (and didn't disable it somehow in openfirmware).

I burned my Ubuntu disk from an Ubuntu i386 system. A Windows machine should be ok.

Non-Apple keyboard should not matter. I do know that the boot is touchy and you may have to mash <kbd>C</kbd> (press & release it at different times) - holding it down on startup may not work.

If you only have a PC keyboard, the open-firmware shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> instead of <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. <kbd>Super</kbd> is also known as the "Windows" key.

Comment: I don't have a apple disk anymore, but the emac reads cds that i put in.

Comment: it doesn't read the Ubuntu CD right? try burning another

Answer (score 1):

Hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key, then wait until the cursor turns into an arrow.  You should see a CD with a penguin beside it.  Click on it, then click the arrow to the right of it.